# What is the difference between GridLayout and Grid

Tags: qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

What is the point of having a `GridLayout` component, when there is a `Grid` component? From what I can tell, they seem to be doing the same thing.

- Grid: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-grid.html
- GridLayout: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-gridlayout.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The components from the `Layout` module added in `Qt 5.1` allow you for example to automatically resize your layout dynamically so if the user is able to resize the `Window` containing the given `Layout` it will grow/shrink properly. It also allows you to have certain elements fill the rest of the space in your `Layout` while others have fixed size.

You can read a bit more about `Layout` in [the documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquicklayouts/qml-qtquick-layouts1-layout.html) and also see there is also [RowLayout](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquicklayouts/qml-qtquick-layouts1-rowlayout.html) and [ColumnLayout](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquicklayouts/qml-qtquick-layouts1-columnlayout.html)

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail? If I add a GridLayout, it will absolutely not resize at all. I can use `anchor.fill: parent` but this does also work on a Grid

Comment: Try ``Layout.fillWidth: true`` + ``Layout.preferedWidth: [...]``on childrens